# How can I get the total predicted for each factor level, and not for each observation?

Tags: r, data-analysis, prediction

I am working through a predictive analytics course, and I am having trouble getting a similar output with my data versus the output that was given in the sample code.  My desired output is a prediction (in column d3hat) for each age group level (in column AORlevels.)

This is what is given in the code/output:

[Sample code/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FzDR.png)

This is the code/output that I am getting:
[My code/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuXp9.png)

The only difference I can see between my data and the sample data is that I have an extra variable.

Here is the data I am working with:

[d3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWDEp.png)

My ultimate goal of the assignment is to make a graph and interpret results--it's a predictive analytics course, but there is a heavy coding component that I am struggling with.  I have taken a course in R, but it is still challenging for me to adapt another's code to fit the data I am using.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

Mo

I have tried matching the code exactly (changing variable names, etc.) but I still get the same result as if I were to just use the variable name itself (d3$d1.AORlevels).

[Code/output using exact sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ZKY.png)

Using this code, I was not able to successfully create the d3hat column. The number of rows in newly created newdata1 is 4 rows (which is great), but the variable I'm trying to create with the predictions (newdata1$d3hat) has 7,836 rows (one for each observation.)  This result leads me to believe that I am missing a very simple and obvious coding component that I am not aware of.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you be able to 1. share the code you have written, and some of your data, enough that someone else can have a go at replicating what you've done? Thank you!

Comment: Here's a guide on what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example